# Regarding the usage of exec

Tags: python

I read that one should avoid using `exec` and `eval` unless it's really needed, so I was wondering if the following cases are valid usages of it, and, if they aren't, what could I use instead?

In a method of the `Npc` class I need to change a variable from an instance of the `Place` class. Like this:

In `Npc.move(self,destination)`:

```
exec "%s.matrix[self.position[0]][self.position[1]] = False" % (self.place)
```

Where `self.place` is the the name of the `Place` instace where the npc "is". Which could give when executed, for example:

```
bedroom.matrix[0][0] = False
```

What I can think of is: create a method on the `Place` class to do that (set the position as `False`). But is it really better to do so? That way I'd end up with some one-line functions that are only used once.

I also used `exec` to call an external method:

```
def save(self):
    """
    Saves the object instance to the database.
    """
    exec "sql.routines.%s.add(self)" % (self.__type__)
```

Where `__type__` can be `Place`, `Npc`, and so forth... I know I could use a bunch of `if`'s, but... is it really better to do so? I mean, I can't seem to see the "danger" here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than storing the string name of a `Place` in `NPC` just store an instance of the `Place` class, and call that instance directly.

```
class Npc:
    def __init__(self, place):
        self.place = place

    def move(self, destination):
        self.place.matrix[self.position[0]][self.position[1]] = False        
        ...

place = SomePlace()
npc = Npc(place)
npc.move("foo")
npc.place = SomeOtherPlace()
npc.move("bar")
```

The second example could almost certainly also be redesigned to exclude the use of `exec` although it's impossible to say how without the details of the `sql.routines` code (I imagine it might look something like a generic `add` method than uses `instanceof` to specialise on types where necessary).

Unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise I would strongly suggest using an existing sql library such as [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Answer (score 2):

neither of those are good use cases to use eval the first one could be much better bt having a rooms object

```
rooms['bedroom'] = matrix
rooms['yard'] = matrix...
```

then do something like

```
rooms[self.place][self.position[0]][self.position[1]] = false
```

the save could be better as

```
getattr(sql.routines,self.type).add(self)
```